# Android delete settings/files from Internal Storage

Tags: android, storage, internal

IS there any function which can delete all folders of my application in Internal Storage. I need a way to reset my application and to clear all saved files/settings/databases in my application's folder in internal storage. Which is the best way to achieve this?

EDIT:

Code I'm using :

```
String name = context.getFilesDir()+"/documents/users/stampiiii/2345/data/";
Log.e("","path : "+name);
File myDir = new File(name);
myDir.delete();
boolean iff = myDir.delete();
Log.e("","iff : "+iff);
```

Thanks in advance for suggestions/help/advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Context.deleteFile()](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/content/Context.html#deleteFile%28java.lang.String%29)

```
public abstract boolean  deleteFile  (String name)
```

**Delete the given private file associated with this Context's application package.**

Or

```
File file = new File("File path");
                    boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

Comment: How can I delete `databases` folder in my internal memory? Or even files folder?

Comment: I suggested you two methods for delete files.

Comment: I'm using the updated code in my question and it's returns me `false` everytime

Comment: ok, very clearly, if your directory contains any file then directory is not deleted, so to delete any directory your directory must be empty.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a programmatic way of doing it, but you can do it manually in `Settings->Applications->Manage applications-><Your app>->Clear data`

Answer (score 0):

yes but add to the others that there is a getExternalStorage call of some kind then I would add get a listing with file.listFiles then to that there not all devices actually do what the spec says so smartie is to put something somehow so you can tell which files are yours as if you del someone else's files that is baddo delux